# Query database table field for a string of characters

Tags: mysql

I have a table field 'new_options' that can contain data of the folling types:

1. something including string-a
2. something including string-b
3. nothing at all
4. something else not including string-a or string-b

I want to set $options_exist='no' if conditions 1, 2 or 3 are met.
Or $options_exist='yes' if condition 4 is met.

I have this so far that works for 1, 3 and 4:

```
$str='string-a';
$opts_exist = strpos($product[new_options], $str);    
if ($opts_exist == true) {
        $options_exist='no';
 }
elseif ($product[new_options]==''){
$options_exist='no';
} else {
$options_exist='yes';
}
```

How can I add in a condition for string-b too?

Comment: Show us sample data and expected result. You mean return `Yes` if not exist row with `('string-a', 'string-b', null)`?

Comment: `strpos` doesn't return true or false, it returns the position where the string is found, or `false` if it's not found.

Answer (score 0):

Do it in the SQL:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN new_options LIKE '%string-a%' THEN 'no'
            WHEN new_options LIKE '%string-b%' THEN 'no'
            WHEN new_options = '' THEN 'no'
            ELSE 'yes'
       END AS options_exist
FROM yourTable
```